# Dropbox Image gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, dropbox

I am trying to make a image gallery in wordpress from Dropbox. In wordpres I installed the plugin "Cloud Folder Share" that read information from Dropbox specific folder. Problem is that it make a list of all files that I have in this folder but I need that he show my this files/images. Can somebody help my with this things. Or knows somebody other solution to create a image gallery from Dropbox or Google Drive shared folder? 
May be somebody know what I can edit in php files to get the images not the name of it and link to it on dropbox.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Core API would be the best choice for this. You can find the official PHP SDK for the Core API  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php).

There's a getting started guide [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php).

The full documentation is [here](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/).

For example, you can use this method to get a thumbnail for an image file. Here is a [link](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_getThumbnail) for this.

It's really pretty simple. Here is a snippet from http://davidwalsh.name/generate-photo-gallery Follow this link and you'll found a simple way to solve your issue (demo included).

```
/** settings **/
 $images_dir = '<path-to-your-dropbox>';
 $thumbs_dir = '<path-to-your-generated thumbnails>';
 $thumbs_width = 200;
 $images_per_row = 3;

 /** generate photo gallery **/
 $image_files = get_files($images_dir);
 if(count($image_files)) {
 $index = 0;
 foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
 $index++;
 $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
 if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
  $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
  if($extension) {
    make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width);
  }
}
   echo '<a href="',$images_dir.$file,'" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery"><img src="',$thumbnail_image,'" /></a>';
   if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>';                                                  }
 }
 echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
  }
 else {
  echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
}
```

I hope now you leads towards a positive solution.